# rmarkdown beamer reduce font size for references

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

How can I reduce the font size in the references section of an beamer presentation written in rmarkdown?
I was able to get the references on multiple slides, but they are so many, I would like to also reduce the font size.

```
---
title: "minimal reproducible example"
author: "User"
date: "April 2022"
output: beamer_presentation
bibliography: references.json
---

## Main question



How can I reduce the font size in the references section of an beamer
presentation written in rmarkdown (@xie_etal20, @rcoreteamLanguageEnvironmentStatistical2021)?

I was able to get the references on multiple slides, but they are so
many, I would like to also reduce the font
size.


## References {.allowframebreaks}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the font size like this:

```
---
title: "minimal reproducible example"
author: "User"
date: "April 2022"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
bibliography: test.bib
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{CSLReferences}{\tiny}
---

## Main question



How can I reduce the font size in the references section of an beamer
presentation written in rmarkdown (@einstein)?

I was able to get the references on multiple slides, but they are so
many, I would like to also reduce the font
size.


## References {.allowframebreaks}
```

[image]